# How to make Syncfushion ej-grid editable

Tags: syncfusion

I am trying to use Grid that is specified in the following
https://www.syncfusion.com/products/essential-js2
I can see there are attributes like [allowSorting],[allowFiltering],[allowGrouping] to achieve sorting,filtering, grouping etc. But how can I make the grid editable?
Following are the functionalities that I am looking for - edit existing row, add new row, delete new row.

Answer (score 1):

Currently Essential JS 2 Grid component doesn’t have Editing feature. This is considered as a feature request and working on this with high priority. This feature will be available in our upcoming releases.

Comment: We are using Angular 2. So should I look into the following link ?http://ej2.syncfusion.com/documentation/grid/                                             Does this grid has any editable features?

Comment: May I get to know the expected date of release for the same? I am planning to use the grid but need to know when this feature would be made available.